# C# Creating a list of a custom class. Values are not saving properly

Tags: c#, excel, class, visual-studio-2015

I have a custom class "Actions" which I am loading with 2 properties: a range, and a string called "Action". I am looping through an excel doc using range.find to try and store a list of the ranges. However, (and I saw that this is just by design how it works), Each time I change the value of the properties of "currentAct" when I find a new range, it sets the properties for all of the objects in the list that have been previously added. How do I get around that so the list is of all of the different values?

```
Excel.Workbook activeWorkBook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
Excel.Worksheet activeWorkSheet = activeWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Range colRange = activeWorkSheet.Columns["A:A"];
Excel.Range resultActionFirstRange = null;    
Excel.Range resultActionCurrentRange = null;

/*This is my custom list: ActionRangeList*/
List<Actions> ActionRangeList = new List<Actions>();

/* This is what I'm using to set the properties of the class before adding to the list */
Actions currentAct = new Actions();

string actionValue;
string DBName;
string TblName;
int actionCol;
int actionRow;

string searchActionLabel = "Action=>";
string searchDBLabel = "DatabaseName=>";
string searchTblLabel = "TableName=>";

        resultActionCurrentRange = colRange.Find(searchActionLabel, Type.Missing, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        //get action
        while (resultActionCurrentRange != null)
        {
            if (resultActionFirstRange == null)
            {
                resultActionFirstRange = resultActionCurrentRange;
                actionCol = resultActionFirstRange.Column + 1;
                actionRow = resultActionFirstRange.Row;
                actionValue = (string)(activeWorkSheet.Cells[actionRow, actionCol] as Excel.Range).Value;
                currentAct.Action = actionValue;
                currentAct.actionRange = (Excel.Range)(activeWorkSheet.Cells[actionRow, actionCol]);
                ActionRangeList.Add(currentAct);
            }

            else if (resultActionCurrentRange.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1) == resultActionFirstRange.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1))
            {
                break;
            }
            //search for next range
            resultActionCurrentRange = colRange.FindNext(resultActionCurrentRange);
            //check if we looped back to the beginning yet
            if (resultActionCurrentRange.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1) != resultActionFirstRange.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1))
            {
                actionCol = resultActionCurrentRange.Column + 1;
                actionRow = resultActionCurrentRange.Row;
                actionValue = (string)(activeWorkSheet.Cells[actionRow, actionCol] as Excel.Range).Value;
                currentAct.Action = actionValue;
                currentAct.actionRange = (Excel.Range)(activeWorkSheet.Cells[actionRow, actionCol]);
                ActionRangeList.Add(currentAct);
            }
        }

    private class Actions
    {
      public Excel.Range actionRange { get; set; }
      public string Action { get; set; } 
    }
```

Comment: You keep using the same instance of the class. Create a new instance each loop iteration.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

As Anthony Pegram said I just needed to create a new instance each loop iteration. Thanks!